# TFS 2018 Scheduled backups error TF401002

Tags: tfs

I am trying to create scheduled backups on my TFS server.
This phase passed (no problems here):
[image]

But in next phase (When i clicked on Configure button) i got this error:
[image]
[image]

Here is the log file:
https://file.io/ZvJKLB

** I am already changed LogOn services 'Sql server', 'Job agent' to my user.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Did you get any related error info in Even View on the server?

Comment: No, never got any error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to give db_backupoperator.

if you dont have security issues the cleanest way is to give "sysamin" permission to Matan user.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding but - where can i do that?

Comment: from SQL Server Management Studio you can do this.  You either look for the Security => Logins section under root or select the appropriate database and look for Security => Users section.

Comment: Im just entered to: Security => Users and i dont see my user "Matan". When im try to add new user i got this error:
https://ibb.co/bCgwwS
https://ibb.co/bAvvqn

Comment: It seems that you are using your Desktop PC to configure this, which I suppose it is for your own use. If I am correct why dont you just use "sa" account which already have superadmin permissions. otherwise, If it is windows user you need to add it as windows user.

Comment: Yes im using desktop pc. Where i can set to tu sa instead of Matan? In LogOn tab on sql and jobAgent services? if yes- im just tried and i see only Administrator, no sa. and administrator login failed. About user Matan- Its already windows user. what am i missing?

Comment: One more think- 'Matan' is the one and only user in this PC. so 'Matan' is Administrator

Comment: your TFS is probably using Integrated Security. Thus Set proper Service Account (or at least check) then go on to SSMS. Under Security > logins you need to see this account. If it is not there you need to add it.

Comment: Yes the user there...With the old name (In hebrew):
https://ibb.co/jJLj0n
I cant add new user under Matan name because the hebrew name alrady exists. and this is same user. just renamed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165397/discussion-between-simonare-and-matan-marciano).

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind this error could be masking the underlying error.

During migration to Azure DevOps Server 2020.1, I received the same error and had to review the scheduling tool's log file to find that the log file for one of the databases was full.

In both the TFS 2018 configuration tool and the Azure DevOps Server 2020.1 configuration tool, there is a link to the detailed log output.  **Make sure you review the detailed log output before adjusting permissions on your SQL server.**

*

> [Info   @15:34:39.634] Granting account DOMAIN\YourServiceAccount
> permissions to initiate database backups of
> Tfs_YourCollectionsName [Error  @15:34:39.649]  Exception Message:
> **TF30042: The log file for the database is full.** Contact your Azure
> DevOps Server administrator to back up the transaction log for the
> database to free up some log space.
> *

The fix was to perform a LOG backup to SQL Server's 'NUL' output and *then* configure scheduled backups:

```
BACKUP LOG [Tfs_YourCollectionName] 
TO DISK = N'NUL' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'Tfs_YourCollectionName-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10
GO
```